# Querying nested fields in Flink SQL 1.11

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, pyflink

I have a schema that looks like this:
Table: org_table

```
`transaction_amt` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
`transaction_adj_amt` BIGINT NOT NULL ,
`event_time` TIMESTAMP(3),
`fd_output` ROW<`restime`  BIGINT `outcome` VARCHAR(64)>,
```

When I query this table like this:

```
SELECT transaction_amt, transaction_adj_amt, event_time, fd_output.restime as response_time, fd_output.outcome as outcome,  YEAR(event_time), MONTH(event_time) 
           FROM org_table
```

When running the above query on the table I am getting an error. Is there something I am missing here?

```
scala.MatchError: CAST (of class org.apache.calcite.sql.fun.SqlCastFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to pay attention to the input parameters of Flink built-in functions, such as YEAR and MONTH functions, their input parameters are date types

Flink built-in function description can refer to
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/functions/systemfunctions/

Comment: If I remove the row fields from the query, it works even with YEAR and MONTH (built in functions)

Answer (score 0):

Try `fd_output.get(0)` to access restime, `fd_output.get(1)` for outcome.